# Ionic Push Notification on database Insertion

Tags: node.js, push-notification, ionic2

Deal All,

I am working on Ionic2 which receives push notifications. It is working fine. I want to fo a step further. I need to automate the push notifications. I am using PHP with mySQL. I also have NodeJS WebApi. Is there any possibility in NodeJS or PHP to send Ionic Push notification? I have followed the following tutorial in NodeJS but I get 401 Unauthorized error:

[ionic-push-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-push-server)

Following is the error:

```
STATUS: 401
HEADERS: {"date":"Thu, 13 Apr 2017 19:13:09 GMT","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","content-length":"196","connection":"close","server":"openresty","via":"1.1 vegur","access-control-allow-credentials":"true","access-control-allow-methods":"HEAD,GET,POST,PATCH,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS","access-control-allow-headers":"DNT,Authorization,X-CSRFToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type"}
BODY: {"meta": {"version": "2.0.0-beta.0", "status": 401, "request_id": "00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444"}, "error": {"link": null, "type": "Unauthorized", "message": "JWT decode error occurred."}}
```

Comment: the error message tells you why you receive an 401 , `JWT decode error occurred`

Comment: Oh great. Thanks. I realized the API key was wrong. Thanks a lot. Just solved the problem with your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ionicPushServer = require('ionic-push-server');

    var credentials = {
        IonicApplicationID : "IonicAppId",
        IonicApplicationAPItoken : "IonicApplicationAPIToken" //You need to generate from app settings
    };

    var notification = {
      "tokens": ["your", "device", "tokens"],
      "profile": "AppProfileNameInSmallLetters",
      "send_to_all": true,
      "notification": {
        "title": "Hi",
        "message": "Hello world!",
        "android": {
          "title": "Hey",
          "message": "Hello Android!",
          "payload": {
            "category": "Star"
              }
        },
        "ios": {
          "title": "Howdy",
          "message": "Hello iOS!",
          "payload": {
            "category": "Star"
              }
        } 
      }
    };

    ionicPushServer(credentials, notification);
```

Comment: what is IonicApplicationAPItoken and from where can I found it.

Comment: You will get it when you create a push server app at Ionic Push Server cloud. But unfortunatelly they have discontinued the push notification application server or cloud. You can use other free services. The one I used is [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/)